# Why would human resources need my resume and grades at the end of my internship to extend my work contract?

Tags: resume, internship, human-resources

I'm currently an intern in a very large company. My internship will end next month, I really like this job and my supervisor wants me to stay for the summer. He made a demand to extend my work contract and a member of the human resources called me and asked me to send my CV and my grades. This is odd, because I already sent them my resume and grades when I first got hired a few months ago. Even if they "lost" my resume or grades, why do they need them?

Comment: vtc why not ask them instead of us?

Comment: What's your actual issue here? If you already sent them your resume, send it again. That would have been a lot faster than complaining about it here. Have *you* lost your resume?

Comment: @MaskedMan My questions asks "Why" this is part of their process.

Comment: Alright, it is a part of the process for reasons known only to them.

Comment: @MaskedMan I assumed it was part of a standard procedure and wanted to know why. This procedure was described in the accepted answer.

Comment: It is not a "standard" procedure. The accepted answer is a good one, and describes one possibility, but it is not the only reason. There are also plenty of companies which just "upgrade" your internship to employment without additional paperwork.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because their formal employment process requires them. To be consistent if they require them from external hires they will require them from you.

It may be that the internship prices is entirely separate from the hiring process. This is rather common - disjointed processes across large organisations are the norm.

Or it may be that the HR teams are doing the right thing and not holding copies of your data any longer than they need to. In one of my previous roles, we would discard most copies of candidates CVs, applications etc as soon as we had hired or turned them down.

Comment: +1 And some regulated industries require regularly updated resumes on-file for all staff members incase employees are called upon for subject matter expertise during audits and inspections.

Comment: Another reason may be that this information can protect the company during lawsuits. If someone sues the company based on hiring discrimination, the company now has a record of the resumes of accepted candidates in their recent past. The information can also be helpful as a benchmark for HR when they need to develop job requirements for a posting, or to answer the constant and annoying questions from undergraduates at job fairs that ask "what GPA do I need for a job at your company?"

Answer (score 10):

You have been an intern of that company for a few months now. The resume you sent them before you were hired **is not current** anymore.

You should **update your resume** to include your experience with this company to make it current. Then you apply for an extension of the internship contract formally.

I think this is actually a good sign. They must be happy with your performance so far. You should do what they say if you want to continue to work for them.

Answer (score 2):

Some companies/industries require a current resume as part of an employees paperwork.  For the industry I'm in this is part of the regulatory paperwork for such things as audits (in our case FDA).  It needs to be kept updated every 6 to 12 months.

I got my bachelors in '79 and masters in '83 but I still have to keep updated.